# Comparing a multivariate timeseries to a set of references

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, python

We have a dataset of many multivariate time series. We want to be able to determine if a new time series is 'normal' with reference to our dataset (i.e., was it drawn from the same distribution).

These series may be of variable length and they shouldn't be time warped.

My idea was to compute a 2d histogram from the reference set for each variable, basically the probability of the line graph of that feature falling in a particular square.

Given the new time series we can accumulate the probability through this histogram by finding all the cells it passes through and multiplying their probabilities. However, I'm not sure how to go from these (tiny) probabilities to a *test* for how likely the path is. I'm also not sure how to negate the effect of length, as these probabilities will necessarily be lower the longer the new series is.

Additionally, any pairwise comparison between all of the reference series and the new series is computationally infeasible (as there are many series in the reference and we need the test to be low latency).